# Passing image from form to wordpress using ajax without any plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have made a form on my wordpress theme through which i want user to upload image .This is my HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
<button id="uplod" ">Upload</button>
```

and below is my js

```
jQuery("#uplod").click(function()
{
   console.log("trying to fetch image");
    var selectedFile = jQuery('#file').get(0).files[0];
    console.log(selectedFile);
    var ajaxdata=
    {
        action:"reg_upload_img",
        img:"selectedFile"
    }
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, ajaxdata,function(res)
    {
        jQuery(".divError").html(res);
    });
});
```

and my function in functions.php file of theme is

```
function fiu_upload_file(){
$error = '';
var_dump($_FILES);
wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_reg_upload_img', 'fiu_upload_file');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_reg_upload_img', 'fiu_upload_file');
```

what should i add in my js code and php code so that image of form can be passed to my wordpress directory so that i can save and handle it in wp database

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload files with `jQuery.post()`, only `XMLHttpRequest` can be used with `FormData`and `jQuery.ajax()` can be used which uses `XMLHttpRequest` internally.

```js
jQuery("#uplod").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var fd = new FormData($("#file"));
  fd.append("action", "reg_upload_img");
  fd.append("img","selectedFile");

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  });

});
```

and a small typo with your button's attributes, you have an extra `"`:

```
<button id="uplod">Upload</button>
//----------------^-----------one extra '"' removed from here.
```

Comment: Hey jai ,I followed your code and used 'jQuery' instead of '$' .but i got error as TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.

Comment: one more thing i forgot to add you need to use it in HTML5 only.